# How can I retain geotagging information on my iPhone pictures?

Tags: photos, iphone

Most of my phone's memory (almost 11 GB's of it) resides in my pictures and videos. I want to clear most of it but not even my completely empty iCloud storage can handle all of it. Anyways, when you're looking at your photos and you zoom out into "years" and you click one of those years, a big map will pop out and you'll literally see every single place you've taken these pictures at. I think that's really cool since I went to a lot of places last summer and in general think it's a cool feature. Back to the point, is there any way I could save that location information when I *export* these pictures to my laptop? Would a copy/paste just be sufficient? I don't have a Mac either, so I don't know if it will be harder or impossible. And if it is possible, is there some sort of app that you can use on your laptop to pull up that same view you have on your iPhone and see everywhere you took your pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just copy those images. Those location information is coded into EXIF data. It will not be deleted upon transfer.

Comment: Sweet! Now is there any way you know of that I can pull up that EXIF data on a map on my laptop or an app that allows you to do so?

Comment: If you use iPhoto, then upon adding the images, you can see them on a map.

Comment: Yeah, but my OS isn't Mac... Any other app that works the exact same way that works on Windows?

Comment: Nevermind! I actually looked that up myself and found this thing called Picasa by Google, it isn't as cool looking as the default one on my iPhone, but it'll do! If you have any better suggestions let me know! Thanks for your help!